# drupal: let users upload content type

Tags: drupal, upload, module, drupal-content-types

we want users to be able to upload an instance of a certain content type themselves using a form. Content type contains text, images and should be linked to the user uploading it. 
We've got the Profile2, account profile and IMCE modules installed but we can't seem to find a module that lets users upload a content type. 
Is this even possible, if not what are possible alternatives?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "upload content type", I'm guessing you mean create a new piece of content of a certain type? To create a new content type, [CCK](https://drupal.org/project/cck) is a good choice. CCK will allow you to add a variety of different fields to a type of content that users can add. After you install CCK, you can add fields by visiting admin/structure/types and clicking the "Manage fields" link for the desired content type. You then have to be sure that the user belongs to a role that can add/edit that particular type of content (managed with permissions at admin/people/permissions. This is assuming you're using Drupal 7. Now when users go to add this new type of content, they will be presented a form with the fields you configured using CCK.